# Enumeration of tree vertices such that each vertex has unique neighbor appearing before it

Tags: algorithms, graphs, trees

*(Diestel, Graph Theory)* **Corollary 1.5.2:**  Every tree has an enumeration of the vertices $\{v_1, v_2\ldots v_n\}$ such that each vertex $v_i$, with $i\geq 2$, has a unique neighbour in $\{v_1, v_2\ldots v_{i-1}\}$.

I am wondering if there is an efficient algorithm that could produce such an enumeration in $O(n)$.

Answer (score 1):

Pick an arbitrary root. Do a preorder traversal. Now, each vertex has a unique neighbour prior to it in the ordering, namely its parent.

Comment: Could you describe what you mean by pre-order traversal? AFAIK, pre-order traversals are only defined for binary trees while the theorem holds for any type of tree.

Comment: Preorder traversal is easily extended to non-binary trees by the straightforward generalisation: you visit the root first, then for each of the children, you recurse into the subtree rooted at that child.

Comment: The order in which you process the children doesn't matter.